# How to extract a token using <eval> in splunk xml dashboards

Tags: xml, splunk

I want to do something like

```
<eval token = "new_name">extract value from $name</eval>
```

and use it in my splunk query in the xml structure

```
<row>
    <panel>
      <title>Name</title>
      <table>
        <title>Name</title>
        <search>
          <query>
             Splunk query
          </query>
        </search>
      </table>
    </panel>
</row>
```

How do I do that, could some please help.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Before we can say how to extract  value from `$name$` we need to know what the contents of `$name$` look like.

Comment: @RichG $name contains a string which can either be a single word or consists of space separated words. I would use the expression ```if(match($name, "\s"), mvindex(split($name, "."), 1), $name)``` to extract the desired value.

Comment: What I want to do then is to include the extracted value in my splunk query so as to get all the events in which that extracted value is present.

Comment: You already have the expression needed to extract the desired value.  The only problem I see is you use a single `$` whereas Splunk tokens must be bracketed by them.  That is, `$name$` rather than `$name`.